# Reuploading Photos taken from FB groups to a Blog will cause copyright issues?

Tags: images, blog, copyright

I am running a blog in the tech niche. Specifically computer niche. I am using images taken from my camera phone. I joined many FB groups that are relevant to my niche.

I know using someone's photo without paying or giving credit is illegal. Let's avoid stock photos. Those are taken by real professionals and they deserved it.

Let's Say someone uploads a photo of a VGA card to sell on a buy and  selling group. Once he sold the product of course he is going to remove  it. So what if I use that image in my blog?

What's the harm? I don't think that user is checking the internet for  the rest of his life whether someone uploads an image of his VGA card?   In fact, there are millions of images that have the same angle of the photo. Using stock photos will be a different story as the uploader is doing it in business purpose and he is always keep an eye for his pictures.

Copyright will be an issue if the user complain it right? Here I am talking about a regular user who uploads an images to a FB  group without knows these things.

So am I jeopardizing my google AdSense account if I do this? Sure if the user contacts me I will remove it. But according to google's eyes what you think?

How google identify I paid for my photos or not?

I am not here to justify what I am doing. I am just curious.

Comment: Google is operating under the DMCA and anyone operating under the DMCA is not an arbitrator. Google does not identify if the materials were paid for or not. It is not lawful to make a fraudulent claim; Google is not placed in a position of jeopardy by acting on any claim in good faith. If the claim is false the burden falls on the person publishing the materials to counter the claim. If I were hosting your site I would act the same ... tell you there is a claim, and remove the content within the time frame unless you can and do dispute the claim.

Comment: If I were hosting your site, could I ask that you make it easy for anybody with a problem with an image to contact you directly, say have a place on your site where somebody can tell you they are the owner of the image and want the image removed? It would make life easier for me and perhaps google as well.